# elliptic curve scalar addition

Tags: elliptic-curves, homomorphic-encryption

say there is an homomorphic cryptosystem on elliptic which allows unlimited addition and only one multiplication.
So in order to same the mult operation for a later functionality, I need to add a scalar to a ciphertext.
That is not a defined function. Still, is there some way to go about it ?

Comment: Anything wrong with: one takes the scalar, encrypts it with the public key, then uses the homomorphic addition?

Comment: Not clear, to do the scalar multiplication, you still need group multiplication and the number itself if encrypted another problem.